# submitting a form inside a modalbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

submitting form with jQuery

works

```
         $('#testform').submit();
```

doesn't work

```
              $('#testform').submit(function () {
                 alert('test1');
                return true;
              });
```

This is just an exmaple but at times i'd like to do stuff before submission of the form. Like for example submit the form using `$.POST`

Update:

If I keep both then the `$.POST` has no value because the form still gets submitted the traditional way, without ajax...

```
                    $("#testform").submit(function() {
                            $.post('/myajaxcontroller', function(data) {
                                $('#result').html(data);
                            });
                    });
                    $("#testform").submit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example submits the form. The second example sets an event handler for when you submit the form. You need both;

If you need to to something asynchronous, you're forced to `return false` from the submit handler so the form doesn't get submitted, and you can submit the form in the AJAX callback.

```
 // Send an AJAX request before submitting the form
 $('#testform').submit(function () {
     var form = this;
     $.post('/myajaxcontroller', function(data) {
         $('#result').html(data);
         // everything is good, submit the form on our own
         if (data.looksGood) {
             form.submit();
         }
     });

     return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#testform').submit();
```

This line **call** the submit immediatly (the submit is running now!)

```
$('#testform').submit(function () {

    // Do some stuff

    return true;
});
```

This line only define which callback function **will be called** before the submit of the form.
You should take care at the documentation, jQuery function do not do the same job with and without parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Use prevent default to stop default submit from happening

```
  $("#testform").submit(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault()  //< ---- Add this
       $.post('/myajaxcontroller', function(data) {
       $('#result').html(data);
        });
  });

  $("#testform").submit();
```